# In Application_BegineRequest, how can I know when the request is for a MVC controller or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the Application_BeginRequest event in the global.asax, I want to fire some logic ONLY if the request is for a controller action method.

Currently things are getting called when a request is for a resource like a .js file etc.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using global.asax, use an action filter then you can decorate the exact controller or action to perform your logic.

Override one or all of the following methods:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Decorate your action or controller

```
[MyActionFilter]
public class MyController {
    [MyActionFilter]
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209(v=vs.100).aspx for other action filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of `HttpContext.Current.Request.Path` which gives the url of the resource.
This is the answer to your question but, I like Jasen's answer better.

Answer (score -1):

In your web.config, under the element `<system.webServer>` you can add the following node

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />`

This will tell IIS to only run the Manager Modules for known request types. If your server is setup for extensionless or .mvc for MVC requests, they will still be processed.